# Read from end of file in Fortran 90

Tags: file-io, fortran

My question is how to read beginning from the end of a text file.
For example,

```
do
  read(1,*) i
  print *,i
end do
```

will read each line in the file 1, and print the contents to the terminal.  How would I do this starting from the end of the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible. Reading always starts from a certain point, and proceeds forward. By default it starts from the first byte; but you can jump to some other location.

The critical issue is, in a free-format file, there is no way to know where the lines start unless you read the file. You could jump to the last byte, check whether it is a line separator or not, then jump to the byte before it if it wasn't, crawling back till you find a newline, but it would be very inefficient.

A better way would be to read the whole file once, remembering where the newlines were; then iterate this array backwards, jumping to each line's start position to read it. This is not as inefficient, but it is not great, either.

The best way, if you have the memory for it, is to read in the whole file into an array of lines, then reverse the array in-memory.

Comment: Ok.  Thanks for your response.  How would I jump to a certain line?  Say I'm searching line-by-line for a particular number in a file, but I know that it's somewhere after the first 500,000 lines.

Comment: As I just explained, you can’t, without counting the newlines by reading all lines from the beginning. It’s like telling someone to turn into the fifth street left while driving blindfolded - you can approximate, by knowing an average length of a city block, but you’re much more likely to end up crashing into a building when you make the turn, rather than hitting that street you wanted

Comment: In the same way, you could say that if you knew the average line length to be e.g. 5 bytes then 500000th line might start around 2500000th byte - but tbere’s no guarantees.

Comment: Ok.  I understand now.

Comment: Of course, it's possible to read a file from its end to its first character.  A simple solution involves `access=stream` and `backspace`

Comment: @evets: By characters, yes, in a way - but even so, a read always pushes the file pointer forward after each character. By lines, no, without some back-and-forthing, as described above. Also... .from Intel Fortran docs: "Backspacing from the current record n is performed by rewinding to the start of the file and then performing n - 1 successive READs to reach the previous record." - efficiency-wise, horrible.

Comment: @Amadan, you should read about `stream`, `inquire`, and file positioning.  You do not need to rewind to the start of a file and do n-1 reads.  You use `read(fd, pos=n)` to position the file pointer to position `n` for the read.

Comment: Those were not my words, it was a response to your suggestion for `BACKSPACE`, and a quote from the manual to show that it is a bad suggestion. `READ(fd, pos=n)` does not suffer from this "feature", but then we weren't talking about `READ`. BTW, your 10-minute quick exercise implements my first (very inefficient) suggestion.

Comment: @Amadan, **very inefficient**?.  Have you measured my 10-minute exercise?  Optimization is left as an exercise for OP.   OP seems to want to write out a file line by line in reverse order.  You wrote **It is not possible.**  Sorry, but you are wrong, and I have demonstrated that you are wrong.

Comment: @evets You are arguing semantics, and it's tiresome. I said it is not possible to read backwards; then listed some possible workarounds. The workaround you implemented (without ever conceding that it was included in my answer), consisting of lots of skips backwards followed by reading forwards, is inefficient comparing to the other workarounds, in particular to reading the whole file then reversing it in-memory, especially large files on classical disk drives, given the way the disk access is optimised (flash drives may not care too much).

Comment: @Amadan, there is nothing semantic nor needed to be conceded.  You wrote, and I quote again, **It is not possible.**  It is possible.  As far as efficiency is concern, my 10-minute hack, reverses a 16760 line file with 471618 characters to stdout in 4.8 seconds.  The same file can be reversed by FreeBSD's rev(1) utility in 1.64 seconds.   Three times slower than an optimized Unix utility.  Not too inefficient for a 10-minute hack.

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve what you want by using `inquire`, `access=stream`, and the `pos` tag in the read statement.  A quick 10 minute exercise gives the following.

```
program foo
   implicit none
   integer fd, i, j, m, n
   character, allocatable :: s(:)
   character :: c
   open(newunit=fd,file='foo.f90',access='stream',status='old', &
   position='append')
   inquire(fd, pos=n)
   allocate(s(n))
   m = 1
   do i = n-1, 1, -1
      read(fd, pos=i) c
      s(m:m) = c
      if (iachar(c) == 10) then
         do j = m, 1, -1
            write(*,'(A1)',advance='no') s(j)
         end do
         m = 1
      else
         m = m + 1
      end if
   end do
   write(*,*)
   do j = m-1, 1, -1
      write(*,'(A1)',advance='no') s(j)
   end do
   write(*,*)
   close(fd)
end program foo
```

Save this into a file named foo.f90, compile, and run. Someone here can make it more elegant.  Edited original version:  don't need to use array sections for `s(j)`.